# Can someone explain how this method works?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The method is about to delete a city for the smallest population!

The method:

```
public void delCity(long population) {
    if (population== 0) {
        System.out.println("There is no city!");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (cities[i].getPopulation() < population) {
            for (int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) {
                cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
            }
            cities[--index] = null;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

So the part i don't understand is the body of the second for-loop, for example how `cities[j] = cities[j + 1];` works and what does the `cities[--index] = null; i--;`? I would really appreciate your responses.

Comment: No, this method removes all cities with a population under a given limit. By the way, it does it in a very inefficient manner (O(N²)) and should be banned.

Comment: Lol and how would you code this method?

Comment: In a single loop, pack to the left all kept elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This loop is shifting all the values of the array [from the position *i*, that is the city to delete]. (Because the array is static, otherwise there is null between elements )

```
for (int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) {
    cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
}
```

Then is setting last element to null and decreasing index;

```
 cities[--index] = null;
```

Here an explaination of the shifting:
[image]
[image]

As mentioned into comments. Your complexity is O(N²). But just changing your data structure (for example, using Lists), you can improve it to O(N).

Comment: Thanks for illuminating my problem :)

Comment: @VigKilla moreover, just changing your data structure, for example, using lists. You can improve your complexity to O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: "This loop is shifting all the values of the array" ... From the actual position which is where the city with population below the threshold is.

Comment: @aquiros that is what i mean :) thanks now i'll edit

Answer (score 2):

```
cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
```

The above statement sets the city at index `j` to the city at index `j + 1`.

```
cities[--index] = null;
```

This statement just sets the last index of cities to `null`.

As such, there is no removal of an element. The element to be removed just gets overwritten with the next element. And the loop does this for all elements following the one to be deleted. At the end, we are left with the last element which is set to `null`.

Leaving the explanation aside, the code is quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but why is it inefficient?

Comment: As mentioned in one of the comments, it has a complexity of O(n²). This is because you are using a nested for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I commented the code as any more elaborate explanation would be superfluous in such simple context.

```
//Scan all the cities, from i = 0 to i = index -1
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) 
{
    //Check it cities[i] has LESS population than specified
    if (cities[i].getPopulation() < population) 
    {
         //We need to remove cities[i]
         //We shift all the subsequent cities 
         //(cities[i+1], cities[i+2], ... cities[index-1] one position LEFT,
         //thereby overwriting cities[i] and so deleting it

         //Shift all the subsequent cities left
         //We start this for FROM i, so the first iteration is
         //cities[i] = cities[i + 1];
         //The second is
         //cities[i + 1] = cities[i + 2];
         //and so on. We STOP AT index - 2 (note the strict less than)
         //So that j + 1 is AT MOST index - 1
         for (int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) 
         {
                cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
         }

         //Since j was at most index - 2, the cities[index - 1] was not
         //overwritten with the next one. Naturally as there is no next one
         //for it.
         //This last city is now duplicated (the copy is at index - 2) and
         //Must be overwritten with null.
         //Also index, which keep track of the number of cities must be
         //decremented (here the pre-decrement -- is used)
         cities[--index] = null;

         //cities[i] was the deleted city. But now it contains cities[i + 1]
         //Which is a totally different city!
         //If we continue the for now, we will go to the NEXT city, as i 
         //will be incremented, to keep i the same one more iteration, we
         //decrement it. This way we process (the new) cities[i] one more time.
         i--;
    }
}
```

Use the old pencil and rubber until you fully understand the algorithm, really, there is no better way.

Comment: Thank you, i will.

Comment: I got a question so we got an array of five elements String [] array={a,b,c,d,x}; and i want to delete x , so using the previous code (its in for-loop) array[i]=array[i+1]; does it mean that first element(a) will be replaced by the next element(b) example: array[0]=array[1]; ?

Comment: The code `array[i] = array[i + 1]` is executed only from the position of *x* onward. So if you want to delete *x*, then No, *a* won't be replaced. Nothing will be replaced as the inner loop would shift element up to *d* at most (so for *x* it doesn't cycle even once).

Answer (score 0):

`index` is the size of array `cities`. So, when you come to specific position where `cities[i].getPopulation() < population` is `true`, you will move all cities from position `i + 1` to the end of array `index - 1` to positions `i` to `index - 2`, and you do that with:

```
for (int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) {
                cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
            }
```

So, city with small population on position `i`, now `j`, will be deleted by overriding it with `citiescities[j + 1]`, and the `citiescities[j + 1]` will be overrided with `citiescities[j + 2]`, etc until the end of array. So, on position `citiescities[index - 2]` will be same as `citiescities[index - 1]`, so we need to delete it to, so you place `cities[--index] = null;`, where `index` will be first decremented (thats why `--` will be left from `index`), and `cities[oldIndex - 1]` will be `null`. This will also help with `for` loop not to go until first `index` value location in array, but until the last city in the `array`, that is present.

Now, since your index i will be incremented in next for loop step, but you moved next city on position i, you must decrement `i` to check that city, thats why `i` at the end.

Note, that with this you will still have a full long array as before, so filled with some nulls if there are cities with less population than stated. Maybe better approach will be to copy it to new array with size `index`, that you got at the end of `for` (note: something similar what `ArrayList` does when you remove item from it).

Comment: `index is the size of array cities` assumption?

Comment: yes, based on this: for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) if index > cities.length this will produce exception... so I assume its the size of array... or at least index < cities.length...

Comment: Thanks for your response.